# How can I put the data inside the MuiDataTable with these codes?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui, mui-datatable

This is my code and how can I push the data inside the MuiDataTable of data={data} with my componentDidMount(). I can already fetch the data from my user collection, however, I do not know enough about mui datatable on how to pass it there. This is the one mui datatable -

```
https://www.material-ui-datatables.com/

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import {firestore} from './../../../firebase/firebase.utils';

const columns = ["Display Name","Email"];


class UserTable extends Component {
    
    state = { user : null}
    
    componentDidMount() {
        firestore.collection('users')
            .get()
            .then( snapshot => {
                const users = []
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data()
                    users.push(data)
                })
                this.setState({ users : users})
                // console.log(snapshot)
            })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }   

    render() {
        return ( 
        
            <MUIDataTable
                    title={"Users"}
                    columns={columns}
                    data={data}
                    // options={options}
            />
         );
    }
  
}
 
export default UserTable;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass array of object formatted with your column names' as key like 
  `{"Display Name": value, Email:other value}`. 
You need to pass the state into the constructor like:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { users: [] };
  }
```

And then you just  have to pass `this.state.users`to MUIDataTable props data, like:

```
 <MUIDataTable
        title={"Users"}
        columns={this.columns}
        data={this.state.users}
        // options={options}
      />
```

For the example I used axios ro fetch data but this work with firestore to:

```
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { Component } from "react";
import * as axios from "axios";
class UserTable extends Component {
  columns = ["Display Name", "Email"];
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { users: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/users.json")

      .then((res) => {
        const userData = res.data.map((u) => {
          return {
            "Display Name": u.name,
            Email: u.email
          };
        });
        console.log(userData);
        this.setState({
          users: userData
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
 
  render() {
    return this.state.users ? (
      <MUIDataTable
        title={"Users"}
        columns={this.columns}
        data={this.state.users}
        // options={options}
      />
    ) : (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserTable;
```

With your code this would like :

```
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { Component } from "react";
import * as axios from "axios";
class UserTable extends Component {
  columns = ["Display Name", "Email"];
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { users: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
 firestore.collection('users')
            .get()
            .then( snapshot => {
                const users = []
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data()
                    users.push({"Display Name":data.displayName, Email: data.email});
      
                });
                  return users;})
             .then(userList => this.setState({users:userList});
              
            })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
   
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.users ? (
      <MUIDataTable
        title={"Users"}
        columns={this.columns}
        data={this.state.users}
        // options={options}
      />
    ) : (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserTable;
```

[image: Edit infallible-northcutt-ihbtq]


**UPDATE**:
here you can find a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-firestore-get-data-forked-eymtv) with firestore

Comment: I don't why it's still not working with the return but I can see the data if i will console.log(data.displayName). Also, if i'll try snapshot.map, I'll get an error that says "TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function". So i'm using the snapshot.forEach

Comment: can you show us a console.log of snapshot and I will update my answer with your data structure

Comment: @JenJennie I'm not familiar with firestore but I found a example and based on it I've updated my answer. Sorry for the .map issue

Comment: Thank you so much, it's already fixed. The data is already showing in the table